# Add animation to Chromecast images change

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

My application casts images periodically to external screen and after every image screen turns black for 1-2 seconds. I believe Chromecast loads next image during this time.

Is it possible to handle this time of loading? For example, add animation of image dissapearing, so it will look more "smooth". 
Or another possible solution is to keep previous picture while new one is loading.

**How can I achieve this behaviour?**

I'm using default media namespace: `urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media` and default application ID: `CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`

This is how I cast images:

```
 public void castImage(final String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "casting Image");
    if (mApiClient != null && mApiClient.isConnected()) {

        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Casting");
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
                url)
                .setContentType("image/png")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_NONE)
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .build();
        try {
                mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult result) {
                            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Media loaded successfully");                
                            } 
                        }
                    });
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem occurred with media during loading", e);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem opening media during loading", e);

        }
    } else {
        reconnect();
    }
}
```

*Please tell me if some more code needed. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What receiver are you using? If you are using the Default or Styled receiver, then the answer is no since they don't support that. You would need to write a custom receiver and use a couple of different techniques. For example, you should start sending a list/queue of image urls to your receiver and have your receiver show one item while it is loading the next image in the background so you don't have to "wait" for the next one to be loaded when user wants to see that. In terms of animations/transitions, you cannot do a lot of things but fading in/out seems to be among the smoothest on that device. With a custom receive, you can even play a background music while a slide show is presented on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ali. I'm using default receiver and hoped there's possibility to achieve such behaviour using it. Seems like no. Going to explore Custom Receiver now.